# CRAN finds an warning that R CMD check --as-cran does not

Tags: r, windows, package, cran

I am using 32-bit R 3.1.2 on Windows 7.

I recently conducted an `R CMD check --as-cran` on a recently-developed package and received only the 'New submission' note.  Research here and on R-devel suggested this could be ignored.  I also used `devtools::build_win()` and received no notes or warnings, other than the one mentioned previously.  Further, I built the package locally with `R CMD build` and `R CMD INSTALL --build` and everything worked as it should, including the PDF manual.

Upon submission to CRAN, I was told that a warning was thrown:

```
    This fails to make its manual:

    * checking PDF version of manual ... WARNING
    LaTeX errors when creating PDF version.
    This typically indicates Rd problems.
    LaTeX errors found:
    ! Missing $ inserted.
    <inserted text>
                    $
    l.682 }{}

    ! Missing } inserted.
    <inserted text>
                    }
    l.682 }{}

    ...

    The line appears to be

    \widehat{R_1} = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{c_i/n}}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n{L_i/n}}
```

Additional research here suggests that I use [win-builder.r-project.org/](http://win-builder.r-project.org/) to check my package on the development version and results from that test threw only the "New submission" warning.

I'm at loss.  I can't replicate the error that CRAN found an everything appears to work correctly on my machine and on [win-builder.r-project.org](http://win-builder.r-project.org/), too.

Can someone please help me with resolving this issue?  I freely admit that I am not a LaTeX expert but given that the line wasn't an issue with R 3.1.2 on windows or the development version on win-build, I don't know where to begin.

Package information is available here:

[creelSurvey](http://www.github.com/stevenranney/creelSurvey)

I used the `inlinedocs` package to write my functions and comments.  The warning is coming from the .R, line 127:

[this function](https://github.com/stevenranney/creelSurvey/blob/master/R/SimulateBusRoute.R)

and the .Rd line 39:

[this .Rd](https://github.com/stevenranney/creelSurvey/blob/master/man/SimulateBusRoute.Rd)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 with r-devel by cloning the Github repo and running

```
R CMD build creelSurvey
R CMD check --as-cran BusRouteCreelSurvey_0.2.1.tar.gz
```

**I was able to fix it** by removing DOS end-of-line markers (`^M` or `Ctrl-M`) from `man/SimulateBusRoute.Rd`.  I don't know the easiest way to do this on Windows (you could look for a `dos2unix` utility, or possibly come up with a `readLines` solution.

I don't know how it will work across platforms, but this seems to work for me:

```
fn <- "MakeAnglers.Rd"
r <- readLines(fn)
writeLines(r[nchar(r)>0],con="new.Rd")
```

I would (1) look for (possibly obscure) warnings in the [R Extensions manual](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) about end-of-line markers and then (2) report this, either to the CRAN maintainers or by posting on `r-devel@r-project.org`.

In general you should be able to detect these problems if you can set up a test build on a Linux system; I don't know of an equivalent of `win-builder.r-project.org` for Linux systems, but http://travis-ci.org is a good resource, and [this Github project](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis) is a good way to get started with R projects on Travis. (Or you can set your project up on R-forge.) I recognize that this might be more of a project than you're looking for right now, just including it for future reference.

Comment: Ah-ha!  I have been running `R CMD check --as-cran` on the [package name] directory rather than on the `.tar.gz` which is likely the cause of my inability to reproduce the error.

I'll work on the solution you provided.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure that is your problem.  I think it might be an obscure cross-platform issue ... but the `R CMD build ...` process is recommended as best practice.

Comment: This is my first attempt at building and deploying a package to `CRAN` and I thought I had identified and resolved all notes, warnings, and issues.  Surprisingly, other than a suggestion to disambiguate the title of the package, the LaTeX/PDF warning was the only other issue.  Given that package development is something I see myself doing in the future, setting this up on R-forge would be a useful exercise.  Again, I'll work on the solution you provided and report back.

Comment: OK.  I would definitely encourage you to report this on r-devel (a very quick search for "dos", "end-of-line", etc. in the r extensions manual didn't turn anything up)

Comment: My own quick search turned up little as well.  I'll report this evening.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it worked great.  I resubmitted to CRAN and, in the meantime, reported the issue to r-devel.  I was told that the issue was a function of "user error" rather than a cross-platform issue.  Apparently, the line of `LaTeX` that was causing the issue should have been all on one line rather than spread across multiple lines: [thread on r-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-January/070346.html).  My attempt at making the `.R` file easier to read thwarted my abilities to package everything up.